# Как отключить пользователю интернет

Tags: ubuntu

Как можно отключить сеть пользователю на Ubuntu 14.04/ 16.04?
(Пользователь — не администратор.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Команда для отключения интернета нашлась на [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102005/disable-networking-for-specific-users):

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p all -m owner --uid-owner <user-name> -j DROP
```

Эта команда сбрасывает все  пакеты, исходящие от пользователя .

Теперь нужно сделать это изменение постоянным.
В ответе на [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102005/disable-networking-for-specific-users) предлагают для этого создать в директории `/etc/network/if-up.d/` скрипт, который вызывает команду выше:

```
cd /etc/network/if-up.d/
gksudo gedit block_user
sudo chmod +x block_user
```

У меня это почему-то не сработало:(, после перезагрузки `sudo iptables -L` показал таблицу без упоминания этого пользователя.

Другой способ нашелся на [ubuntu.ru](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0#%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8). 
Кроме помещения скрипта в `/etc/network/if-up.d/`, там предлагают вызывать скрипт из `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

добавляем последней строкой

```
post-up /etc/network/if-up.d/block_user
```

Проверяем после перезагрузки:

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination        

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination        

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination        
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             owner UID match <user-name>
```

Теперь работает.

**UPD**: Поскольку `gksudo` больше не рекомендуется и его собираются отменить, редактирование можно сделать, например, так: 
(лучше открыть для этого еще один терминал)

```
sudo -i
```

вводим свой пароль и дальше работаем от имени rootа. Эта команда также перемещает в /root. Далее:

```
root:~# cd /etc/network/if-up.d/
root:~# gedit block_users &
root:~# chmod +x block_user
root:~# gedit /etc/network/interfaces
root:~# exit
```

*Обратите внимание*: если закрыть терминал с rootом или сделать `exit`, `gedit` закроется. Поэтому это можно делать только после окончания редактирования.
Источник:[askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/284717/244413).